# Deleting nib files from a signed OS X app

Tags: macos, nib

Is it possible to delete the nib files from a signed Mac OS X app; if yes, what are the ramifications of it ?

Comment: I don't see why not, but you will break the code signature at least.

Comment: Not necessarily. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [“Changes That Don't Invalidate a Code Signature” in *Technical Note TN2206 OS X Code Signing In Depth*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG402):

> Removing files from `.lproj` directories inside `Contents/Resources` will not invalidate the code signature, but adding or changing files will.

So you won't break the code signature if the nib file is part of a localization.

Otther than that, the app will work if it doesn't need the nib file (for example because you're not using that localization), and will probably crash or fail in a weird way if it does need the nib file.